# Returning Site name that triggered Web App Code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

On Classic Google Sites, I have some HTML on a filecabinet page.  This is a button that runs a gadget.

```
<div style="text-align:left;display:block">
<a href="https://script.google.com/a/MyDOMAIN/macros/s/AKfycxLblah_mp-Z5DWetc/exec" imageanchor="1" target="_blank"><img alt="Run web app" border="0" height="40" src="https://sites.google.com/a/MyDOMAIN/MySite/Preview%20Btn.png" width="120">
</a>
</div>
```

The test code I am using for the gadget is:

```
function doGet() {
  var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();
  var myactivesite = site.getName();
  Logger.log(myactivesite);
}
```

When I press the button on the page I get:
TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

If getActiveSite is returning the site that has the container, how do I return the site name to the script that will add a container to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I ended up passing a parameter in the html with the link to the gadget and amending the doGet() code.

```
href="https://script.google.com/a/MyDOMAIN/macros/s/AKfycxLblah_mp-Z5DWetc/exec?Client=Site-Name"
```

So I can slice off the "Client=" to get the site name that I entered and in the javascript can still use site.getAllDescendants  etc.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ActvSite = e.queryString.slice(7);
  var myDomain = 'https://sites.google.com/a/MyDOMAIN/';
  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(myDomain+ActvSite);
```